# Function Isolating Camera's LED Light and java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera$Parameters

Tags: java, android, scope, camera, android-emulator

I am struggling to control the LED light next to my camera in the app I am trying to make for my own education purposes. I have tried to follow the methods in http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-turn-onoff-camera-ledflashlight-in-android/ , but I am trying to make the function more abstract and more general in order to increase reusable functionality and make the code more readable.

Upon creating my activity we first check, using PackageManager, that a LED camera does in fact exist. I then open the camera. The onClick function runs the functions changeScreen() and toggleLight(). Here you can see the clear advantages of using abstraction, ie toggleLight() works as a black box, using code set out elsewhere. The changeScreen function I know is correct, well before adding toggleLight() it was working correctly.

As the code should be correct, as it was taken from the example, I believe I have a problem with variable scope.

1) Where does the boolean isLighOn need to be declared, in the function or in the activity?

2) Same problem with the camera variable

How else should I go about creating an abstract function toggleLight()? I have checked around on this website, but a lot of posts send you to the link provided above. Moreover I believe an answer to this question would help many users and would provide reusable code.

Here is my code so far and I have posted the error I am getting below again.

```
package com.mycompany.myapplication;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public RelativeLayout container;
    private boolean isLighOn = false;
    private Camera camera;

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        // if device support camera?
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
            return;
        }

        camera = Camera.open();

        container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
        container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeScreen(v);
                toggleLight();
            }
        });
    }

    public void changeScreen(View v) {
        ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) this.container.getBackground();
        TextView ON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ON);
        TextView OFF = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OFF);

        if (cd != null && cd.getColor() == getResources().getColor(R.color.BLACK)) {
            container.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE));
            OFF.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ON.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            container.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BLACK));
            OFF.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ON.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void toggleLight(){
        final Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

        if (isLighOn) {

            Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");

            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(p);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isLighOn = false;

        } else {

            Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");

            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

            camera.setParameters(p);
            camera.startPreview();
            isLighOn = true;
        }
    }


}
```

When I load the app on my Android Studio emulator, I get the screen "ON". However, when you click the screen the app crashes. This is only error message I can find in the IDE. I am not sure how to interpret this error message.

[image]

In response to a comment below I am now posting the code containing the permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Does your app crash, or it does not turn flash on/off?

Comment: @AlexCohn When the app loads up it says "ON", then when you click the screen the app crashes. I have edited the question to try to provide more information.

Comment: You should probably copy the error message from that trace into your question. That way it’ll make this question findable to others who run into the same error. (Also, the actual error message is incomplete, truncated in the image you posted.)

Comment: @sideshowbarker Ok, but its not clear to me which is the error that should be put in the title, I see just lots of errors

Comment: @Jurassic the `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera$Parameters` is the important part—the part that indicates where the code is failing

Comment: Anyway, it seems like you need to add a null check for `p` before you actually make any calls using it.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Im not sure why that would help, surely a null check would return null and then nothing would happen. I cant see why its flagging up Camera Parameters as a problem

Comment: The call to `camera.getParameters()` fails because `camera` is **null** at this point (beginning of the `toggleLight()` function). One of the causes could be that the app did not request the permission to use camera properly.

Comment: @AlexCohn I am fairly sure I have added the permissions correctly, I have added my manifest file so that other people see whether I was correct

Comment: I should say that emulator can provide inconsistent camera behavior. Have you tried a real device with real flashlight?

Comment: @AlexCohn Sorry just done that and it works, my apologies

Comment: Very good, no need to apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on an emulator to produce reliable camera behavior. Always verify camera-related code on real device!